# I need to know how to read an input from a html form in JavaScript and separate the digits after the decimal point

Tags: javascript, html

For example, if the number put in the html form was 30.1 I need to separate the 30 from the 1 in javascript thanks Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it to string first, then use `String.prototype.split` method. For example

```js
const value = 30.1;
const separated = `${value}`.split("."); // output will be ["30", "1"]
console.log(separated[0], separated[1]) // "30", "1"
```

if you want to read it as number, you can use `Number()`

```
console.log(Number(separated[0]), Number(separated[1])) // 30, 1
```

Comment: Actually, I need a solution that separate the values with a blank space not a comma

Comment: you just have to replacce `.` in `split(".")` with blank space `split(" ")`

Comment: ...if you replace .split('.') with .split(' '), the input remains a decimal (30.1). try:  const separatedBySpace = separated.join(' ') instead

Answer (score 3):

**It's mandatory to convert number into String for split**

```
let number = 30.1;
let convertToString = String(number);
let splitNumber = convertToString.split(".");
for(let i = 0; i < splitNumber.length; i++)
{
  console.log(splitNumber[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should convert the number into string then using spilt methode

```js
let num = 40.1
let value = num.toString().split('.');
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

this can output strings separated by a space.

```js
const formInput = document.getElementById('formInput')
const result = document.getElementById('result')

function separateDigits() {
  const value = formInput.value
  const separated = value.split(".");
  const separatedBySpace = `${separated[0]} ${separated[1]}`;
  const numbersArray = [Number(separated[0]), Number(separated[1])];
  console.log('string array', separated) // array with truncated number and decimals
  console.log('string by space', separatedBySpace)
  console.log('number Array', numbersArray) // 
  console.log(Number(separated[0])) // truncated number
  console.log(Number(separated[1])) // decimals

  return separatedBySpace
}

result.addEventListener('click', separateDigits)
```

```html
<p>
  type a floating point number(ex: 12.34), click submit. returns '12 34'
</p>
<input type='text' id='formInput'>
<button id='result'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: If you're getting the value from a input field, it's already a string.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text